# Why wont my text have centre vertical alignment

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm creating a hexagonal menu by stripping back http://www.darrencousins.com/rr-blogs/hexagons/CSS%20-%20Hexagons%20v2/

My problem is a just cannot seem to be able to vertically centre the text in each hexagon.

My progress so far can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/z54xj/

Here's the CSS

```
/* Hexagon - Create*/
.hex-row {
    clear:left;
}

.hex-wrapper {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 34px;
    margin-bottom: -48px;
}

.hex-wrapper.even {
    margin-top: 53px;
}

.hex {
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #114781;
}

.hex:before {
    vertical-align:middle;
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    border-right: 30px solid #114781;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.hex:after {
    vertical-align:middle;
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    border-left: 30px solid #114781;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

/* Hexagon Hover */
.hex:hover {
    background: #2C86C6;
}

.hex:hover:before {
    border-right: 30px solid #2C86C6;
}

.hex:hover:after {
    border-left: 30px solid #2C86C6;
}

span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex-wrapper" style="visibility:hidden;"><div class="hex"></div></div>
    <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"><span>hello</span></div></div>
    <div class="hex-wrapper" style="visibility:hidden;"><div class="hex"></div></div>
</div>

<div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
    <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex">hello</div></div>
    <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="hex-row">
    <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
    <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
    <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add these to the `.hex-wrapper

```
line-height:100px; /* same as div height */
text-align:center; /* for horizontal centering */
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/z54xj/2/)

Comment: Perfect - Thanks
As per Alek's answer below, I can also remove display:inline-block from the span

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` and `text-indent` also remove from `span` `display:inline-block`

**css**

```
/* Hexagon - Create*/
.hex-row {
    clear:left;
}

.hex-wrapper {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 34px;
    margin-bottom: -48px;
}

.hex-wrapper.even {
    margin-top: 53px;
}

.hex {
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #114781;
    line-height: 92px;
    text-indent: 15px;    
}

.hex:before {
    vertical-align:middle;
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    border-right: 30px solid #114781;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.hex:after {
    vertical-align:middle;
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    border-left: 30px solid #114781;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

/* Hexagon Hover */
.hex:hover {
    background: #2C86C6;
}

.hex:hover:before {
    border-right: 30px solid #2C86C6;
}

.hex:hover:after {
    border-left: 30px solid #2C86C6;
}

span {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z54xj/3/)